# Analytics Api how to get the time the event occurred?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

is there a way to get the time the event occurred (using analytics api)?

I cannot see it in any of the metrics, or find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query [ga:datehour](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_datehour) and [ga:minute](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_minute) to save on dimensions since a single API request is limited to 7 dimensions. So, you will only be missing the second of the occurence

Answer (score 2):

There are dimensions for [hour](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_hour) and [Minute](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_minute) but nothing strictly for time. I dont think its anything they will be adding soon even though it would be nice.  But you could send in a feature request for it http://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/list

Comment: Also, if you need a specific day, you would need to add one more dimension - date :)